# Spring Data REST - collectionResourceRel vs path

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Data REST. `RepositoryRestResource` annotation has two different fields: `path` and `collectionResourceRel`. What's the difference between those two? I can't figure this out by reading the documentation.

`path` is described:

> The path segment under which this resource is to be exported.

and `collectionResourceRel` is described:

> The rel value to use when generating links to the collection resource.

In all code examples I've seen these two properties where the same. Is there any case when they differ? And what is the actual difference between them?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For example, for entity `User` the default values will be:

**path** = `users`

**itemResourceRel** = `user`

**collectionResourceRel** = `users`

Example:

**GET /users**  (path: `users`)

```
"_links": { 
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users"
        },
        "users": {  <-- collectionResourceRel
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users"
        }
    }
```

**GET /users/1** (path: `users`)

```
"_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"
        },
        "user": { <-- itemResourceRel
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"
        }
    }
```